# Unable to fetch user input from drop-down list

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4

I've been trying to fetch user input from a simple drop-down list to fill it into a `<p>` tag but can't seem to get it done.

The following is my javascript:

```
<script>
    function changeText() {
        var textDDL = document.getElementById("DDL1");
        var text = textDDL.options[textDDL.selectedIndex].value;

        var test = document.getElementById("test");
        test.innerHTML = text;
     }
</script>
```

The following is my HTML code:

```
<p class="first">
                    <label for="first">From</label>                     
                    <input list="countriesDL" name="country" class="form-control" type="text" id="DDL1">
                    <datalist id="countriesDL">
                        <option value="Afghanistan" class="form-control"></option>
                        <option value="Albania"></option>
                        <option value="Algeria"></option>
                        <option value="Aland Islands"></option>
                        <option value="American Samoa"></option>
                        <option value="Anguilla"></option>
                        <option value="Andorra"></option>
                        <option value="Angola"></option>
                        <option value="Antilles - Netherlands"></option>
                        <option value="Antigua and Barbuda"></option>
                        <option value="Antarctica"></option>
                        <option value="Argentina"></option>
                        <option value="Armenia"></option>
                        <option value="Australia"></option>
                        <option value="Taiwan"></option>
                    </datalist>

                </p>
<button id="info2Btn" type="button" class="btn btn-warning leggo" style="color:black;" onClick="changeText()">Let's Go</button>
```

The codes would be triggered by a button press. I've tried reloading the page upon button press to see if it applies the user input, I've tried calling the function upon clicking the button. Can't seem to see what's wrong with it.

Comment: can you include the rest of your script, and HTML

Comment: From where you are calling the changeText() function .

Comment: Hi, I've added in my HTML the script as you see is all that I'm using to test right now.

Answer (score 1):

**[UPDATED]** Is this what you are trying?

```js
function changeText() {
    var textDDL = document.getElementById("DDL1");
    var text = textDDL.value;

    var test = document.getElementById("text");
    test.innerHTML = text;
 }
```

```html
<p class="first">
                    <label for="first">From</label>                     
                    <input list="countriesDL" name="country" class="form-control" type="text" id="DDL1">
                    <datalist id="countriesDL">
                        <option value="Afghanistan" class="form-control"></option>
                        <option value="Albania"></option>
                        <option value="Algeria"></option>
                        <option value="Aland Islands"></option>
                        <option value="American Samoa"></option>
                        <option value="Anguilla"></option>
                        <option value="Andorra"></option>
                        <option value="Angola"></option>
                        <option value="Antilles - Netherlands"></option>
                        <option value="Antigua and Barbuda"></option>
                        <option value="Antarctica"></option>
                        <option value="Argentina"></option>
                        <option value="Armenia"></option>
                        <option value="Australia"></option>
                        <option value="Taiwan"></option>
                    </datalist>

                </p>
<button id="info2Btn" type="button" class="btn btn-warning leggo" style="color:black;" onClick="changeText()">Let's Go</button>
<p id="text"></p>
```

Comment: Hi, somewhat, but because I'm using bootstrap for my dropdown list, the solution doesn't really work for me still. I've updated my codes with my HTML.

Comment: That is datalist. Then you can use `onchange` for input tag.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
function changeText() {
   document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = document.getElementById("DDL1").value;
}
```